# Getting Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure dynamically where I have a main clause and a where clause:

```
CREATE ROCEDURE [dbo].[spLocal_GetData]        
    @CreatedOnDate DateTime      
AS
    declare @MainQuery varchar(max),      
            @WhereClause varchar(1000) 

    Select @MainQuery = 'Select column from Table T1'
    Select @WhereClause = ' Where  T1.CreateOn >='+@CreatedOnDate
```

Now while executing the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @CreatedOnDate datetime
SET @CreatedOnDate =GETDATE()

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[spLocal_GetData] ,@CreatedOnDate
GO
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Edit1:**

```
declare @MainQuery varchar(max),      
@WhereClause varchar(1000)      

Select @MainQuery =N'Select ..'
Select @WhereClause = N' Where  T1.CreatedOn>=@CreatedOnDate'


EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[spLocal_GetNonConformance] 
   ,N'@CreatedOnDate DateTime'
GO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: @jarlh using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to concatenate a datetime value with a string `' Where  T1.CreateOn >='+@CreatedOnDate` , Datetime being a higher precedence data type sql server tries to convert the string value to datetime and fails.

You method is prone to sql-injection you should use dynamic sql for this. Although for this simple query you do not even need dynamic sql but assuming the actual query is a bit more complex and you actually need dynamic sql for it you would do it something like this.....

Try this, it will also protect you against sql-injection attack......

```
CREATE ROCEDURE [dbo].[spLocal_GetData]        
    @CreatedOnDate DateTime      
As   
BEGIN
        declare @MainQuery nvarchar(max)

SET @MainQuery = N'Select column from Table T1'
               + N' Where  T1.CreateOn >=  @CreatedOnDate'

Exec sp_executesql @MainQuery
                  ,N'@CreatedOnDate DateTime'
                  ,@CreatedOnDate 

END
```

Comment: Now Getting 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime'

Comment: @Simsons update your question with what you have written now, also just to confirm column `CreateOn` is a date/datetime datatype column ?

Comment: Yes Createon is DateTime

Comment: in that case it must work, update your question with what you have tried now and lets see where are you going wrong.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with M.Ali's code and a basic table (called Table :P ) which works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c70fd/1

Comment: @M.Ali Made an Edit to the Question

Comment: @Simsons have a closer look at your edit and my suggested solution do you not see any difference at all :(

Comment: Ok, I have to add sp_executesql as well , letme try

Comment: yes that's the trick to make your query parameterised and avoid parameter concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `DateTime` to `varchar` before appending it to dynamic sql

so

```
Select @WhereClause =' Where  T1.CreateOn >='+convert(varchar(20),@CreatedOnDate,120)
```

will work for you.

Comment: this solution will fix the date conversion issue but this is as **putting lipstick on a pig** . please do not suggest poor programming practices , thank you

Comment: I agree with M.Ali, and also, have you tried the suggested answer before posting ?